# Devices in same vlan cannot ping each other - ARP Issue

Tags: arp, cisco-nexus

The environment is running with Nexus 9K in NXOS mode. Both are in vPC mode and running hsrp with N9K1 active and N9K2 standby. Due to vPC both nodes are running Active/Active for HSRP.

Now the devices in the same vlan are having arp issue. For example Device-A can not ping Device-B. However, when we ping Device-A from Device-B both bi-directional ping works.

Any suggestions would be helpful. I want to avoid giving static arp entries in the nodes.

Comment: The ping failure message will give you the best clue as to what went wrong. It sounds like you have a closed firewall rule that is being opened from one end, then the firewall times out, and you must again open it from inside.

Comment: Also, the problem is that questions about the hosts are off-topic here. A host firewall or ARP table is off-topic. We could help with the network devices, but not your hosts. You could ask about host problems on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Hmmm the actual issue is with ARP. I can redirect the question to server vault. However ARP is related to network that's why I posted here.
There is no firewall placed in the middle of network. Just layer2 connectivity with Layer3 interfaces acting as Gateways or the host machines.

Comment: I hope server fault don't redirect this question to networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: A host implementation of a protocol is off-topic here. We could help with the protocol theory, but not fixing the way a host does something. Obviously, the network works, so we are left with malfunctioning hosts, and that is off-topic.

Comment: I disagree especially if you understand the problem

Comment: As it explains in the box above, if you disagree with the closure, you can take your objection to [meta] and let the community decide. How your hosts actually create an use an ARP table is off-topic here. The theory of the protocol is on-topic, and we can (and have, if you search) explains how it is supposed to work. If your hosts are not doing it correctly, then we cannot help with that.

Comment: What a stupid person you are?
ARP is below Layer 4 of TCP and is on topic.
Windows or Linux can become L3 routers.
And I am just referring to a question related to ARP. This problem can be reproduce if instead of Windows a router is used. 
You really disappoint me on your judgement for this making Off-Topic based on your user reputation.
Go and read https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
I am wasting my time here.

Comment: There is no call to be rude. Yes, ARP is on-topic for protocol theory, but a host implementation is off-topic. Windows, Linux, and other host OSes are off-topic here, but are well covered on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Insulting people is never a way to get help. As Ron explained, your question is off topic here. You can consider asking it on [sf].

Answer (score 4):

A ping test result (failed) is a only hint at, but never a proof of failed ARP resolution.

Suspected ARP problems must be diagnosed on *both* end systems (usually it takes something like `arp -a` or `arp -na` to display the ARP cache's content). If both end systems have the respective peer's IP to MAC mapping in their ARP caches, then it's not an ARP problem.

Classically the problem of asymmetric ping results is a local firewall policy on one of the end systems that allows outgoing ICMP Echo requests and incoming ICMP Echo responses (--> Ping successful), but drops incoming ICMP Echo requests (--> ping fails).

Then you may also want to cross-check that the Nexus have the given end system's MAC addresses in their CAM tables on the expected ports and VLANs `show mac address-table interface ...`

Comment: Let's assume Device-A is windows 2008 and Device-B is esxi server.
I checked in arp -a in windows machine. There wasn't an entry for device-b.
I ssh into the device-b and ping the device-a. Then there is arp entry for device-b in device-a.

In nexus, the arp entry stays intact even before doing any ping or else.

Comment: Yes of course.  ARP Cache entries have a lifetime - usually 5min for end hosts, 4hrs for routers. If the end systems haven't been talking to each other for <cache lifetime>, then the entries are flushed from the caches, and ARP resolution will happen at the start of the next communication attempt. To be sure you do not have an ARP problem, you _must_ look at the ARP cache on _both_ end systems.

Comment: This is the output: Client Machine (10.3.1.98)

C:\Windows\system32>ping 10.3.1.116

Pinging 10.3.1.116 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.3.1.98: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.3.1.98: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 10.3.1.116:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Comment: @MuneebAli how are your clients and your layer 3 interface configured.

Comment: @MuneebAli please edit and add the command outputs to the original question, using the "{ }" formatting tags, and also include the ouput of `arp -a` and `esxcli network ip  neighbor list` (as shown in http://buildvirtual.net/viewing-the-arp-table-on-an-esxi-host/)

Comment: Host-10.3.1.98
{C:\Users\muneeb.ali>arp -a

Interface: 10.3.1.98 --- 0xc
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.3.1.24             00-25-b5-00-00-1d     dynamic
  10.3.1.29             00-90-a9-e4-e8-24     dynamic
  10.3.1.80             00-50-56-a9-8a-5a     dynamic
  10.3.1.102            00-50-56-a9-27-7e     dynamic
  10.3.1.103            00-0c-29-84-3c-23     dynamic
  10.3.1.110            00-0c-29-74-6d-b9     dynamic
  10.3.1.116            00-50-56-9a-a0-bd     dynamic
  10.3.1.255            ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static}

Comment: @user56700:
Clients and devices are configured on Vlan1031. It has multiple windows servers, esxi, vCenter, iSCSI storage etc with gateways on Nexus9K. On nexus9k pair, hsrp configured with vPC facing downwards.

Comment: @Marc 'netztier' Luethi:
I am unable to add all the details in the comments

Comment: @MuneebAli edit the _question_ to include more information, not the comments. If you can show that it's an actual networking problem, related to the Nexus's configuration(s), then the discussion may continue

Comment: @MuneebAli  Consider showing the (sanitized) outputs of  A) switchport configuration of the given end systems.  B) `show running-config vpc` of the nexus switches along with `show running-config interface XXXX` for vpc peer link and keepalive link interfaces.  C) `show spanning-tree vlan VVVV detail` for the VLAN in question (from both switches) D) `show mac address table vlan VVVV` from both switches (may have to truncate a bit) E) `show running-config interface VLAN VVVV` from both switches.